# How can I grant guest accounts read (or read-write) permission on a folder outside their home?

Tags: mount, permissions, apparmor, guest-session

I have stuff stored in an external partition (ext4) that is mounted through `/etc/fstab` to the location `/vms`. Inside that directory, I have a folder `shared` which should be accessible (currently read-only, later maybe read-write) by all local users, including guest sessions.

However, `chmod -R a+r /vms/shared` makes the files world-readable to all standard users, but not for guest sessions, which AFAIK have another layer of restrictions through AppArmor or something like that which denies access to everything outside their home.

I already have a separate account `guest-config` which serves as default profile for new guest sessions (`/etc/guest-session/skel` is a symlink to `/home/guest-config`) to be able to tweak guest profile settings, just in case this will help.

How can I unlock this specific directory (and all its files and subdirectories) to grant guest accounts read-only or read-write access? Using Ubuntu 16.04 btw.

Comment: You need to add rules to `/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/lightdm`. I'd try with doing something similar to the rules beginning with `/usr/`.

Answer (score 2):

(Copied from my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/840555/how-can-i-grant-read-only-acces-to-my-harddrive-to-guest-user/840559#840559), since I saw that first, and it doesn't seem right to mark this as a duplicate of a question asked later.)

Guest sessions are locked down using AppArmor, which uses a long list of special permissions to keep guest users from touching anything. These are accessed from `etc/apparmor.d/lightdm-guest-session`.

On my machine, that file looks like this:

```
# Profile for restricting lightdm guest session

#include <tunables/global>

/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session {
  # Most applications are confined via the main abstraction
  #include <abstractions/lightdm>

  # chromium-browser needs special confinement due to its sandboxing
  #include <abstractions/lightdm_chromium-browser>
}
```

Opening up that "main abstraction" (`etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/lightdm`) gives something more interesting:

```
...
/ r,
/bin/ rmix,
/bin/fusermount Px,
/bin/** rmix,
/cdrom/ rmix,
/cdrom/** rmix,
/dev/ r,
/dev/** rmw, # audio devices etc.
owner /dev/shm/** rmw,
/etc/ r,
/etc/** rmk,
...
```

These are all the directories which a restricted session can access, along with their permissions. If you add your partition and shared folder to that list (with a trailing `/**` to include all subdirectories, and an `r` for read permission), all future guest sessions will have read-only access to it.

For read-write permissions, use `rw`; this is the default permission for `/var/guest-data`. For full permissions, use `rwlkmix`; this is the default permission for guest-owned drives in `/media`. These stand for Read, Write, Link, locK, Memory-map, and Inherit-eXecute: the last one gives execution privileges, but specifies that execution must happen within the current confinement (so you can't break out of the guest restrictions by running a specially-crafted shell script).

Comment: Okay, thanks. How would it have to look like for full read- and write-access?

Comment: @ByteCommander Added more details on that.

Comment: I now added a line `/vms/shared/** r,` right after the `/ r,` line and ran `sudo service apparmor reload`. After that I logged in as guest, but I still can not access `/vms/shared`. Do I also have to grant read permissions on the parent directories explicitly? Or anything else?

Comment: `/` allows read access already, so you should just need to add read-permission to `/vms` as well.

Comment: I have these three lines added now: 1) `/vms/ r,` 2) `/vms/shared/ r,` 3) `vms/shared/** r,` - now I can list the content of `/vms` but not read any files in it (as intended) and I can list and read contents of `/vms/shared`. However, I am sometimes mounting an `encfs` encrypted folder to a subfolder of that. AppArmor still denies access to the mountpoint in that case, I can access it while nothing is mounted there though. How can I enable access to a mounted `encfs` directory there?

Comment: @ByteCommander: Did you figure it out? Asking out of curiosity.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson No, the mounted `encfs` still shows up as binary file for which I have no permissions as guest account. I can only access files and directories on the same file system so far.

Comment: @ByteCommander: What if you replace the third line with `/vms/shared/** rmlixk,`

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Oh wow, it has been two years already... Damn, time flies. Sorry, I must have totally forgotten about this question and just randomly got back to it because I tried it again and googled it, just to be surprised that I wrote this one myself. Anyway, no `rmlixk` or `rwlkmix` permissions did not change anything. The mounted encfs folder is still shown as unknown and unreadable binary file.