# How can I grant read-only acces to my harddrive to guest user?

Tags: mount, permissions, chmod, guest-session

I want to allow 'guest' user to only read files in my harddrive (mounted during startup at '/mnt/blahblahblah' ) . However I don't want them to write anything into it.I'm on Xubuntu 16.04. How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guest sessions are locked down using AppArmor, which uses a long list of special permissions to keep guest users from touching anything. These are accessed from `etc/apparmor.d/lightdm-guest-session`.

On my machine, that file looks like this:

```
# Profile for restricting lightdm guest session

#include <tunables/global>

/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session {
  # Most applications are confined via the main abstraction
  #include <abstractions/lightdm>

  # chromium-browser needs special confinement due to its sandboxing
  #include <abstractions/lightdm_chromium-browser>
}
```

Opening up that "main abstraction" (`etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/lightdm`) gives something more interesting:

```
...
/ r,
/bin/ rmix,
/bin/fusermount Px,
/bin/** rmix,
/cdrom/ rmix,
/cdrom/** rmix,
/dev/ r,
/dev/** rmw, # audio devices etc.
owner /dev/shm/** rmw,
/etc/ r,
/etc/** rmk,
...
```

These are all the directories which a restricted session can access, along with their permissions. If you add your hard drive to that list (with a trailing `/**` to include all sub-folders, and an `r` for read permission), all future guest sessions will have read-only access to it.